# Logic flow - trying to iterate through website pages with BeautifulSoup and CSV Writer

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I can't seem to figure out the proper indents/clause placements to get this to loop through more than 1 page. This code current prints out a CSV file fine, but only does it for the first page.

```
#THIS WORKS BUT ONLY PRINTS THE FIRST PAGE

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv

page_num = 1
total_pages = 20

with open("MegaMillions.tsv","w") as f:
    fieldnames = ['date', 'numbers', 'moneyball']
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    while page_num < total_pages:
        page_num = str(page_num)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.usamega.com/mega-millions-history.asp?p='+page_num).read())

    for row in soup('table',{'bgcolor':'white'})[0].findAll('tr'):

        tds = row('td')
        if tds[1].a is not None:
            date = tds[1].a.string.encode("utf-8")
            if tds[3].b is not None:
                uglynumber = tds[3].b.string.split()
                betternumber = [int(uglynumber[i]) for i in range(len(uglynumber)) if i%2==0]
                moneyball = tds[3].strong.string.encode("utf-8")

                writer.writerow([date, betternumber, moneyball])
        page_num = int(page_num)
        page_num += 1

print 'We\'re done here.'
```

And of course, this only prints the last page:

```
#THIS WORKS BUT ONLY PRINTS THE LAST PAGE

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv

page_num = 1
total_pages = 20

while page_num < total_pages:
    page_num = str(page_num)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.usamega.com/mega-millions-history.asp?p='+page_num).read())

    with open("MegaMillions.tsv","w") as f:
        fieldnames = ['date', 'numbers', 'moneyball']
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)

        for row in soup('table',{'bgcolor':'white'})[0].findAll('tr'):

            tds = row('td')
            if tds[1].a is not None:
                date = tds[1].a.string.encode("utf-8")
                if tds[3].b is not None:
                    uglynumber = tds[3].b.string.split()
                    betternumber = [int(uglynumber[i]) for i in range(len(uglynumber)) if i%2==0]
                    moneyball = tds[3].strong.string.encode("utf-8")

                    writer.writerow([date, betternumber, moneyball])
        page_num = int(page_num)
        page_num += 1

print 'We\'re done here.'
```

Comment: Extract code into functions and troubleshoot them separately instead of reams of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your second code example is that you're overwriting your file each time. Instead of

```
open("MegaMillions.tsv","w")
```

use

```
open("MegaMillions.tsv","a")
```

The "a" opens the file for appending, which is what you want to do

Comment: silly me. that works. but if we wanted to work with 'w' instead of 'a', is there a way to shuffle around the while/fors/etc to make it work? i feel like i got lost in the control flow and it's bugging me.

Comment: Yes, you can move the open before the while loop. That way, you only open the file once and you can write until all the pages are done

Comment: isn't that what I did in the first code? the open before the while loop?

Comment: and if i take out the indent in the while block to line it up with open block from the first example, it throws me a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: If your first code sample is accurate, I don't think it will ever exit the while loop since page_num will always be less than total_pages because you're not incrementing page_num in that loop. My guess is that your for loop needs to be indented one more level so that its inside your while loop. Right now because of its indentation level the for loop is getting the page_num increment instead of the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the suggestions, here's one variation that works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv

page_num = 1
total_pages = 73

with open("MegaMillions.tsv","w") as f:
    fieldnames = ['date', 'numbers', 'moneyball']
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    while page_num <= total_pages:
        page_num = str(page_num)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.usamega.com/mega-millions-history.asp?p='+page_num).read())

        for row in soup('table',{'bgcolor':'white'})[0].findAll('tr'):

            tds = row('td')
            if tds[1].a is not None:
                date = tds[1].a.string.encode("utf-8")
                if tds[3].b is not None:
                    uglynumber = tds[3].b.string.split()
                    betternumber = [int(uglynumber[i]) for i in range(len(uglynumber)) if i%2==0]
                    moneyball = tds[3].strong.string.encode("utf-8")

                    writer.writerow([date, betternumber, moneyball])
        page_num = int(page_num)
        page_num += 1

print 'We\'re done here.'
```

opted for this over the 'a' because then the headerrow gets written for every page.